# Error with opencv lib : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv

I pass a reference to the image into the function as an argument. It is supposed to be possible to pass the list of references to the image, so the list is used. The code looks like this

```
def cleanOCR(borders):
    detectedOCR = []
    print(f'Borders = {borders}')
    for i, image in enumerate(borders):
        image = cv2.imread(image)
        assert not isinstance(image,type(None)), 'image not found'
        edges = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=100, lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=80)    
        a, b, c = lines.shape
```

But I get an error

```
  File "platesOCR.py", line 66, in cleanOCR
    a, b, c = lines.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Im using cv2 version '4.1.1'
The code isn't mine, I'm just starting to deal with OpenCV.

```
print(f'Borders = {borders}') give me right file path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It essentially means that no lines are detected in the image.

To check this, simply print lines. I am guessing it will be empty.

To NOT get an empty np array, try reducing the minLineLength value. Line segments shorter than this value in your image are rejected. So I would suggest reducing this value.

And also of maxLineGap. It is the maximum allowed gap between points on the same line to link them. So your value for this seems higher.